# Not receiving json object after returning boolean value in Spring

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, httprequest

I don't know whether I do it right or not but it works so far.

The GetMapping should produce a json, but how exactly is it supposed to produce one if I'm giving it only one boolean and no Map type ? what is it exactly returning then ?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getIsTrackedHistory/{name}" , produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody boolean getIsTrackedHistory(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
    boolean isTracked = template.getIsTrackedHistory(name);
    return isTracked;
}
```

My request :

```
$http.get(localhostUrl + 'getIsTrackedHistory/' + $scope.name
.success(function (data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); //prints just true or false, which doesn't look at all like a json object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you do here is absolutely right.  when you return a boolean it would be returned as a single object(as a boolean) in json format.
if you return an object that holds more  properties in it, that would be like as a json format.

Comment: I thought that a json format qualifies as [ key : value ] , so how does this apply to my case ? or in my case it is [true] and no value for this "true" key?

Comment: think that if an api returns an object that holds values as such myObject:{status:boolean}, so it returns as "status":true, since here you return straight away a boolean not defined object.

Answer (score 1):

if you want returning key:value style object.
you must return map or pojo.

for example

```
Map resultMap = new HashMap<>();
resultMap.put("success", true);
return resultMap;
```

then you can see return message : {"success":true}

Comment: wouldn't that be a little bit of overkill ?